# Make a list of stations by checking next_station column value

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, many-to-many

How to list all station between selected two stations based on `next_station_id`

For instance, if the user selects origin A station and destination to J than I want to list all stations in ORDER that have set into the `next_station_id` column.

I have an intermediate level of knowledge in MySQL and have no idea how to write such a query.

```
SELECT r.number as route, s.name AS station, s.code AS station_code, rl.name AS line, s.line_two_id AS interchange
FROM stations AS s
         JOIN route_stations as rs
              ON rs.station_id = s.id
         JOIN routes r
              ON rs.route_id = r.id
         JOIN route_lines rl
              ON s.line_id = rl.id
ORDER BY rs.station_order ASC;
```

> I know the above query is just to join table but as I said I have no
>   clue how to write a query to get a list of stations that have been set
>   in `next_station_id`

## route_stations table

[image]

I am also adding a diagram in case anyone wants to look the structure to refer and  suggest

## Diagram

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE 
cte AS ( SELECT station, next_station, 1 route_order
         FROM routes
         WHERE station = @source
           AND route_id = @route_id
         UNION ALL
         SELECT cte.next_station, routes.next_station, cte.route_order + 1
         FROM routes, cte
         WHERE routes.station = cte.next_station 
           AND cte.next_station != @source
           AND cte.station != @destination
           AND routes.route_id = @route_id )
SELECT * 
FROM cte
WHERE @destination = ( SELECT station 
                       FROM cte 
                       ORDER BY route_order DESC LIMIT 1 )
;
```

Wrong route selection (including cycles) allowed - in such case the resultset will be empty.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reference code. Just to confirm `FROM cte` is my `route_stations` table. correct? I would appreciate it if you can little explain how it works for learning and understanding.

Comment: @pixelngrain You need 3 fields - `route_id`, `station` and `next_station`. In your `route_stations` structure last 2 field have `_id` postfix it seems - you may edit. *how it works* I simply get starting station and route number, then iterate one-by-one station until destination (or last route station, if route selection is wrong) reached. Then return the selected stations list. If route may be wrong (destination unreacheable) then uncomment the checking code. !!! Avoid cycle without destination in it !!!

Comment: I am getting error `[42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'RECURSIVE cte AS ( SELECT station_id, next_station_id, station_order ' at line 1`

Comment: @pixelngrain I give a fiddle - the query is correct itself. Specify your DB server version.

Comment: Yes I saw the fiddle. MySQL version is `5.7.19`

Comment: @pixelngrain You should have said that from the beginning. **IT IS CRITICAL!** Sorry, your MySQL version is too ancient, update it if possible.

Comment: I am extremely sorry about that. Okay, cool.. thanks a lot to clarify.

Comment: @pixelngrain Realize the same algorythm in stored procedure form, use temporary table.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot. I am updating MySQL now and hopefully, the query will solve the issue. Thanks a lot once again.

Comment: I have updated MySQL to the latest version 8.0.18 and the query is working exactly the way I want. Only one problem is there. It is not giving the `@destination` row but one row before. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @pixelngrain I thought it would be enough if the `@destination` station was in the `next_station` field. Check now.

Comment: This is a perfect solution. Thanks a lot. I need a lot of advice and support for you all experts. I may come up with more queries in the future.